# how to make the second gui wait until the first one finishes?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have two consecutive guis in one function. 
how can I make the second one waits until I push the exit button on the first one. I searched in the internet and everyone says use uiwait, but where should I use it?
I should menstion that the first gui contains 3 buttons that one of the is supposed to be programmed to quit the gui.

thanks in advance

Comment: `uiwait` is the correct method - show us what you have tried and your more likely to get useful help (and learn more)

Comment: I have tried many things. but the question is I don't know where to put this uiwait. in the gui m.file? in the main function? and even how to write the command. for example uiwait(delete(handles.figure1)) under the desired button callback?

Comment: To see how to use it look at `help uiwait` -> there is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uiwait` should be used in the first GUI, just before launching the second.

E.g.: `uiwait( launch_second_gui );`